# Is a call to '.Result' blocking my thread or just the execution of the current method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

It says in documentation that calling `.Result` or `.Wait()` on a task will cause the calling thread to block and not do any operations, but when I tried to see if it blocked the thread in a test it didn't block the thread but rather the execution of the current scope (the method)

So by "thread" do they mean the current execution flow, because if I call `.Result` I want to block execution to await a value but not the thread (so that other operations running in parallel in the same thread are not blocked)

I have observed that calling either `.Result` or `.Wait()` still allows for parallel execution, so I would like a clear explanation of what the documentation means by thread.

If it does block the thread what is a good way to get a result from a Task from a sync method without blocking the thread

Comment: It does block the thread. What you may be observing is that other work is still happening on other threads. If you want the method to pause but allow the thread to do other work, use `await`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show the actual code, including how you determined whether or not a thread was being blocked.

Comment: ^^ And stop thinking in Threads when using async/Task. That's exactly what that abstraction layer is supposed to abstract _from_.